# Can not get property undefined 'user' ngrx

Tags: ngrx

Am trying to create an auth system for my app with ngrx.

I have the auth.reducer as :

```
export interface State {
  user: User;
  authenticated: boolean;
}
const initialState: State = {
  user: null,
  authenticated: false
};
export type Action = authActions.All;
/// Reducer function
export function authReducer(state = initialState, action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case authActions.AUTHENTICATED: {
      return {
        ...state,
        authenticated: true,
        user: action.payload
      };
    }
    case authActions.LOGOUT: {
      return initialState;
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
export const getAuthenticated = (state: State) => state.authenticated;
export const getUser = (state: State) => state.user;
```

and an index.ts state file, as am planning to add more reducers to this auth module:

```
export interface AuthState {
  status: fromAuth.State;
}
export interface State extends fromStore.State {
  auth: AuthState;
}
export const reducers = {
  status: fromAuth.authReducer,
};
export const AuthState = createFeatureSelector<AuthState>('auth');
export const selectAuthStatusState = createSelector(
  AuthState,
  (state: AuthState) => state.status
);
export const getLoggedIn = createSelector(selectAuthStatusState, fromAuth.getAuthenticated);
export const getUser = createSelector(selectAuthStatusState, fromAuth.getUser);
```

When I try to call this from the component to get user or authenticated status,

```
this.authenticated$  = this.store.pipe(select(fromAuth.getLoggedIn));
this.user$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromAuth.getUser));
this.store.dispatch(new authActions.GetUser());
```

I get this error
[image]

Comment: are you creating a featureModule or importing this at the StoreModule.forRoot in your appModule?

Comment: Am creating a featureModule.

Answer (score 0):

import your reducer to AppModule or your custom module and on the imports add the following

```
import { reducers } from './path/to/your/store/auth/reducer';



import:[
...
StoreModule.forFeature('auth', reducers),
...
],
```

Comment: is it a lazy loaded module?

Comment: Auth module is just a featureModule not lazy loaded

Comment: Try moving your auth reducer to your AppModule and see if the problem is still there, I suspect that you try to select from that state before it initialized